# Show Active TCP connections

Tags: c#, tcp, uwp

I'm trying to show all open TCP connections. But in my Code I'm getting following error:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException 
>   HResult=0x80131539
>   Nachricht = Operation is not supported on this platform.

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetNativeIPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections()
```

And here is my Code, is the problem, that UWP doesn't support TcpConnectionInformation?:

```
try
{
    IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
    foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections)
    {
        Liste.Items.Add(c.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception e1)
```

Comment: @Saruman Thanks for your reply, now I know it isn't compatible,